# Limit the number of keys shown in legend ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Since the ggplot2 version 3.3.5 update, setting breaks to an arbitrary number to limit the number of keys displayed in the legend does no longer work and set the missing breaks to the new NA = gray default instead:

```
df_Test <- tibble(Year = rep(c("2019", "2020", "2021"), each = 3),
                  Size = c(20, 30, 25, 24, 20, 30, 35, 24, 20),
                  Color_Index = fct_relevel(as.factor(1 : 9))
)

Color_Scale <- c("#dce6f2", "#4f81bd", "#254061", "#4f81bd", "#254061", "#dce6f2", "#254061", "#dce6f2", "#4f81bd")

ggplot(data = df_Test, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Size, fill = Color_Index, order = Color_Index)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(mapping = aes(label = Size, group = Color_Index),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 6, stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = Color_Scale,
                    breaks = c("1","2","3"),
                    labels = c("","","")) + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Cohorts"))
```

Does anyone know how I can limit the number of legend keys shown in the new version?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Setting `breaks = function(x){x[1:3]}` for some reason works. I also don't understand why.

Comment: @teunbrand That is also an interesting find, thank you! Wierd interaction isnt it?

Comment: Meanwhile I found out why: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/ffcfaf715cbca377e78a1312bb733e278fa1c888/R/scale-manual.r#L139-L147

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to name the values. But I'm not sure this is what you want:

```
ggplot(data = df_Test, mapping = aes(x = Year, y = Size, fill = Color_Index, order = Color_Index)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  geom_text(mapping = aes(label = Size, group = Color_Index),
            position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5), size = 6, stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = setNames(Color_Scale[1:3], as.character(1:3)),
    breaks = c("1","2","3"),
    labels = c("","",""),
    na.value = "yellow") + 
  guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Cohorts"))
```

[image]

Comment: If I slightly modify your code to "... values = setNames(Color_Scale[1:9], as.character(1:9)),..." so that both the values and names span the entire length of the "Color_Scale" vector, it actually works as desired! Thank you!